# Background color different on either side of container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to be able to extend two divs background beyond their container to the left and right sides of the page whilst the content stays in the container. So far I have. Should I use transforms to extend the two divs to the edge of the page? Thanks

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-lg-4 left"><p>View our rewards scheme</p></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 center"><p>View our latest offers</p></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 right"><p>We're hiring apply now</p></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Something like this? https://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **appearance** of an extended background-color can be done with CSS pseudo elements..

```
.left:after {
    background-color:lightblue; 
    left: -999em;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 999em;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.right:after {
    background-color:#4444ff; 
    right: -999em;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 999em;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/gHFYUnX6hE

Answer (score 0):

No, a background can't go beyond their container.

The overflow style controls how the element reacts when the content is larger than the specified size of the element.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know you cannot extent your background beyond the borders of your container... However, you could use the box-shadow property (css)

[MDN: box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)